# uncaught exception: cannot call methods on tabs prior to initialization; attempted to call method

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery tabs in my project and code for it is written in a js file. This js file is used in a user control and in one place i m facing following error

> uncaught exception: cannot call methods on tabs prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'div.profile-panes > div'

and on the other place the code is working fine.
I am not able to understand why the same code gives error in one place and working fine on another place.

Comment: the failing code might be before the actual initialization of the tabs, (the `$('#tabs').tabs();`)

Answer (score 0):

You should never be trying to call a method 'div.profile-panes > div', I think this means you've got some problems with syntax. Make sure you have the correct brackets and periods around the `$('div.profile-panes > div')` calls.